# Estilos para vista diseño en Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

En Dreamweaver el modo diseño es muy cómodo para editar una página, fundamentalmente para el texto, pero en esta vista no interpreta bien algunos estilos, algo que se podía solucionar con los estilos para modo diseño. Pero ahora estoy mirando y no veo la opción en la versión que tengo, la 21 que es la más reciente. ¿Alguien sabe dónde está o como aplicar estilos solo a la vista diseño?
En la ayuda del programa viene como se hacía en versiones antiguas, los menús de las versiones más avtuales cambiaron hace tiempo.
Gracias.

Comment: A ver si te resulta útil esto https://helpx.adobe.com/au/dreamweaver/using/design-time-style-sheets.html

Comment: Gracias, la he visto y la descripción usa cuadros y opciones que no existen en la versión 21, pero seguiré investigando por ese camino.

Answer (score 0):

Autorespuesta: la opción fue eliminada en una versión anterior, ahora mismo no es posible tener reglas de estilo para el modo edición.